# Intermediate value theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, solution-verification

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and $\lambda$ is a value between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. Prove that $\exists c \in [a,b]$ s.t. $f( c) = \lambda$

Let, $$g(x) = f(x) - \lambda$$

$g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$
$$g(a) = f(a) - \lambda < 0$$
$$g(b) = f(b) - \lambda > 0$$

Since, $\exists c \in [a,b]$ s.t. $g( c) = 0$, we have $g( c) = f(c ) - \lambda => 0 = f(c ) - \lambda => f(c ) = \lambda$

So, is it this simple? Or, am I missing something here? Please correct me if I did wrong. Thanks.

Comment: You are using what you need to prove (when you assume that there is some $c\in[a,b]$ such that $g(c)=0$).

Comment: @CarlosIsraelJrl that is often how the intermediate value theorem is given, and the result derived here is technically a corollary

Comment: If you can apply the I.V.T: Then you are right!!

Comment: @CarlosIsraelJrl The $c$ I am using here was given as a hint.

Answer (score 2):

The proof you have given is acceptable within the context you're working in *assuming* you are allowed to use the special case of the intermediate value theorem about sign changes implying the existence of a zero (as your proof shows, this special case is logically equivalent to the seemingly more general version). If you have not been given the "special case" as an admissible tool, then your proof is circular.

In any case, all the work is in proving the case where $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ have opposite sign and $\lambda=0$. Although, depending on your approach to your problem, and the degree of mathematical sophistication (e.g. some general topology), the "general" version of the IVT can be proved in a fairly straightforward way (using the notion of connectedness, specifically).